# Efficiently drawing large NSAttributedString into NSView on OS X?

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa, nsview, appkit

I'm porting a terminal emulator from Linux to OS X.

In the Linux version, the code always has a handle to a view which it can draw to at any time. And all this drawing is "cached", so that when you draw something once, it's always going to be there, until you draw over it, i.e. it uses a push-based drawing model. In the OS X version, `NSView` uses a pull-based model instead, so you draw when it asks you to draw, however many times it asks you to.

In my drawing method, I'm creating an `NSAttributedString` from the internal Terminal representation, and then drawing it into the current context inside `-drawRect:`, using CoreText's framesetter functions.

This is inefficient for two reasons: one because the changes to this attributed string don't happen as often as `-drawRect`, and two because I have to build up a `CTFramesetter` at each call and draw it, which has proven to be slow as I profiled it.

Alternatively, I have tried to create a `CGLayer` based on the current CGContext within `-drawRect:` but this is resolution-dependent; thus if you move the window from one screen to another with a different resolution (i.e. retina display) it may not draw properly.

What are some alternative techniques for efficiently drawing the kind of attributed string you'd have in a terminal into an `NSView`?

Comment: You do realise you can force a redraw with `setNeedsDisplay`?  I think your problem is a bit like that of a text editor so perhaps study Apple's sample `TextEdit` app: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TextEdit/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, I can force a redraw when the context changes, and in fact I do; but I'll still be redrawing more often than the content is changing. That doesn't solve the initial problem.